# Documentdb invalid string literal token when

Tags: azure, azure-cosmosdb

I managed to save file path into DocumentDB.

When i try to search document using C# with particular path, it throw exception from DocumentDB. The path i try to search is "\\Dev4\ete\" as show in Error message.

When i tried to run below query in portal. It successfully return me result.

Anyone faced this issue before? What might be the root cause?

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: In your screenshot, what is client.Nodes? Is Nodes a client-side list that contains results from a DocumentDB query?

Comment: could you please show the actual query you execute that populates client.Nodes (where is the client.CreateDocumentQuery) code that actually executes the query?)

Comment: Hi Ryan. That node is successfully written to db. I can search for it using portal query as show above. It just give me this error when using the api. I think the '\' is recognized as invalid character somehow. It really annoy me to the point that I really need to change all '\' to '/' before saving path to db so that I would be able to fetch for them late on.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is failing is because '\' is an escape character.

So, when the backend gets your query of "SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.name = "\\Dev4\ete\" it interprets this as \Dev4\ete\ and then that last \ causes the problem because it is seen as a literal escape character with nothing after it.

You should escape each use of '\' with another '\' i.e. 
The example query shown above would be

```
SELECT * FROM c WHERE c.Name = "\\\\\\\\Dev4\\\\ete\\\\"
```

Same as if you had the literal \n in your node name you would need to escape out the escape characters of \n